# Combining certain elements into one function?

Tags: calculus

so I recently ran over a task in my Maths exams that really confused me:

I had certain characteristics given, and my task was, to create a broken rational function, that fullfills all requirements.

The characteristics were something like:

Defenitions set: D=R{-2;2}
Roots of the function: x=1, this root is a double root.
-2 is supposed to be a infinity point (vertical asymptote)

And some others, but for the sake of just understanding, how i do that, those requierments are sufficient.

So i wouldve created a basic function, that fullfills a single requierment, then do that for every requierment, so that i have a few individual functions. Afterwards, i wouldve multiplied every fuction with the other functions.

I hope that my explanation is clear, English isnt my mothertongue, and talking about that in mathematical jargon is kinda hard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Root means that $(x-1$) is a factor. Double root means that $(x-1)^2$ is a factor. Vertical asymptote at -2 means that $(x+2)$ is a denominator so that $f(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x+2)} g(x)$ where $g(x)$ can be another function of $x$ without 1 as a factor.